# Implementing adapter pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

These are my .java classes. Have I implemented the adapter pattern correctly?

**interface Play**

```
public interface Play {

  public void Tune(String Type,String Guitar);

}
```

**advanceTuning interface**

```
public interface AdvanceTuning {

  public void getSharp(String Guitar);
  public void getLowKey(String Guitar);

}
```

**lowkeytuning.java**

```
public class LowKeyTuning implements AdvanceTuning{

@Override
public void getSharp(String Guitar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void getLowKey(String Guitar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(Guitar+": Guitar Tuned to LowKey");
}

}
```

**Guitar.java**

```
 public class Guitar implements Play{

Adapter adapter;
@Override
public void Tune(String Type, String Guitar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")){
        System.out.println(Guitar+": Guitar Tuned to Standard");
    }
    else if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Sharp") || Type.equalsIgnoreCase("LowKey")){

        adapter=new Adapter(Type);
        adapter.Tune(Type, Guitar);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No Such Tuning exists as "+Type);
    }
}   
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter implements Play{

AdvanceTuning aTune;

public Adapter(String Type){

    if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Sharp")){

        aTune= new SharpTuning();
    }
    else if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("LowKey")){
        aTune= new LowKeyTuning();
    }
}

@Override
public void Tune(String Type,String Guitar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Sharp")){
        aTune.getSharp(Guitar);
    }
    else if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("LowKey")){
        aTune.getLowKey(Guitar);
    }
}
}
```

SharpTuning.java is same as Lowkey.java

and I have a client.java class which creates an object of Guitar.java and calls it's method Tune();

Comment: I'd pass the instance of `AdvanceTuning` as a parameter to the `Adapter` constructor rather than passing a string and "parsing" it.

Comment: An adapter normally is used to convert one interface into another (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) what you implemented looks more like the strategy or decorator pattern.

Comment: @Thomas Okay thanks I ll trying passng it as a parameter.

Comment: I have to implement strategy and Decorater too. could you pleasy verify which pattern is this so I can used this example as that pattern

Comment: @Thomas COuld you please share the example that how to pass the instance of advance tuning to adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

Move this code:

```
if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Sharp")){

        aTune= new SharpTuning();
    }
    else if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("LowKey")){
        aTune= new LowKeyTuning();
    }
```

into some kind factory method.

ie

```
static AdvanceTuning create(String string){
 if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("Sharp")){

            return new SharpTuning();
        }
        else if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("LowKey")){
return new LowKeyTuning();
        }
}
```

your adapter, make it to accept not string, but `AdvancedTune`. then you will be able to reuse existing tune if nessesery.
then your constructor will look like that

```
public Adapter(AdvanceTuning aTune){
this.aTune=aTune;
}
```

then you can create your adapter just by `adapter = new Adapter(create(type))`

you could also consider to remove string constants such as `Sharp` or `LowKey` and replace them with enum.

but in general, looking at your code, it brings me question, what is purpose of using adapter for your case? I cant see anything what you can gain from it

Comment: It's just I have to implement 6 design patterns using same example that's why Im using adapter even though there's no need.
Do you got any example in your mind which could be implemented on factory,adapter,facade,strategy,decorater,flyweight patterns?

Comment: @MunaemRudab maybe in this case you should approach this in different way. create class `Guitar` which does not implements `Play` interface, and create Adapter which addapts guitar to let it work as it has `Play`